# Javascript (Jquery or MooTools or pure Javascript) hide Element by content or href

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I have a HTML that looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td nowrap="nowrap">
<a href="/home" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu" >Home</a>
<a href="/somethingelse" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu" >Something Else</a>
<a href="/somethingelse2" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu" id="active_menu_jos_mainmenu_menu">Something Else 2</a>
<a href="/somethingelse3" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu" >Something Else 3</a>
<a href="/somethingelse4" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu">Something Else 4</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

and i need to hide the Element a with content Home, either by href (because its the only element with this href on page) or by content (which is always "Home").

**But the problem is, i can not add ID to Home.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

First element

```
$(".mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu:first").hide();
```

By content

```
$(".mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu:contains('Home')").hide();
```

By href

```
$(".mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu[href='/home']").hide();
```

Comment: +1 for answering both aspects of the question (href and content)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('a[href="/home"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's hide by giving class name which you have

```
give one more class name to the home like test

<a href="/home" class="mainlevel_jos_mainmenu_menu test" >Home</a>

$(".test").hide();
```

for more details see here

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: sorry, i didnt wrote this but i cant change anything in html strukture - so class etc. has to be the same.